# Swift 4: Xib with collection view that reuse cell from storyboard, inner outlets are nils

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, swift4

I have a cell that was used in main storyboard collection view:

```
class TaskCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var exerciseTitle: UILabel!


    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.layer.borderWidth = 1
        self.layer.borderColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.6666666865, green: 0.6666666865, blue: 0.6666666865, alpha: 1)
    }

}
```

I created a XIB with collection view inside and I am trying to use this cell inside XIB`s collection view. The cell is dequeued, **but all outlets inside it are nils**.

```
class AddTaskToSessionVC: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!      
    public var allTasks = [TaskCodableEntity]()

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()    
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.collectionView.delegate = self
        self.collectionView.dataSource = self           
        self.collectionView.register(TaskCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "TaskCell")
        self.getCurrentPatientTasks()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    public func getCurrentPatientTasks() {

       self.allTasks =  API.getTasks()
        }
    }

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return self.collectionView.showNoDataLabel(array: self.allTasks)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.allTasks.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        if let cell = self.collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "TaskCell", for: indexPath) as? TaskCell {
            let taskEntity = self.allTasks[indexPath.row] 
                cell.exerciseTitle.text = taskEntity.title
            ***(Here exerciseTitle is nil)***

            return cell
        }
        return UICollectionViewCell()
    }
}
```

My XIB is look like:

[image]

I tried to instantiate label inside cell, but it still stay as nil
Is there is a way to reuse cells in such way or I should create XIB cell despite of already exists cell?

Comment: where is your exerciseTitle label exist, in which XIB it is there ?

Comment: If your cell is a prototype cell in the collection view you no need to register for the cell, just select the prototype cell in the XIB and set the reuse identifier as "TaskCell" from the attribute inspector right panel and remove the registering code. Connect your cell's label to exerciseTitle variable as outlet clean and build your project.

Comment: @vivekDas see conversation here https://stackoverflow.com/a/51493934/556526

Comment: also select your prototype cell and set the custom class as "TaskCell" and then take outlet of the label to exerciseTitle.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register the xib like this

```
 collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "TaskCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "TaskCell")
```

as this

```
TaskCell.self
```

used when the cell is created programmatically

[image]

Comment: But I do not have XIB of cell, it is class that was used in storyboard

Comment: if you have a prototype cell in IB , then no need to register it only give it identifier and use it inside cellForItemAt

Comment: When I use your line I get an exception: 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle with name 'TaskCell''

Comment: if no nib comment any register line

Comment: If I remove register lines I get next exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'could not dequeue a view of kind: UICollectionElementKindCell with identifier TaskCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'

Comment: @AlexBerd Maybe you didn't set the class or identifier correctly

Comment: see how set identifier

Comment: @Sh_Khan Right, cause your example is from storyboard as I see. If your collection view in XIB you can not add cell inside it (I have no idea why). Your example is exact what I did in my storyboard view controller with this cell. Now I want to reuse it in XIB with collection view, and I have this issue. See the print screen of my XIB attached to the question

Comment: look to this demo https://github.com/ShKhan9/collectionVDemo , you will find how to register it from xib , IB and programmatically

Answer (score 0):

For your easily work with view with xib and it's reuse, I recommend you to see framework [Reusable](https://github.com/AliSoftware/Reusable)

I think in this quote you can find answer on you question. I think you need to make file owner(not view) for your class and you can use `NibOwnerLoadable` and `Reusable` protocols to reuse and load your view more easily.

> Declare your views to conform to NibLoadable or NibOwnerLoadable
>
> Use the NibLoadable protocol if the XIB you're using don't use its
> "File's Owner" and the reusable view you're designing is the root view
> of the XIB
>
> Use the NibOwnerLoadable protocol if you used a "File's
> Owner" of the XIB being of the class of your reusable view, and the
> root view(s) of the XIB is to be set as a subview providing its
> content.

Hope it help you!

Comment: I tried you library, but the result is the same, The inner outlets are nils after dequeue cell

Comment: @AlexBerd your `XIB` look like you insert not `Cell` but usual `UIView` to collection? Maybe this is your problem?